# css: vertical and horizontal align, IE

Tags: css

this code work fine with FF and Chrome, but with IE not.

How fix this code with IE (9,8,7)?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'> 
.center{
    background-color: #336699;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
}
.sub{
    display: table-cell ;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
   <span class="sub">
       Some text text...<br />
       An some more text...
   </span>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: With 120 questions you should know by now that "this works, that doesn't" is totally useless and will get your question nowhere.

Comment: You should add a, preferably the HTML5, doctype and see if that resolves the issue. Additionally, I am presuming your complete source code does indeed include a closing </html> tag ;P

Comment: It seems this happens in 4.01 doctype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it's not working in IE9/8 is because you are missing your DOCTYPE. It still won't work in IE7, but if you make your span display block and adjust your margins, you can get it to look the same. See my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type='text/css'> 
.center{
    background-color: #336699;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
}
.sub{
    display: table-cell ;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .sub {
        display: block;
        margin: 70px auto;
    </style>    
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
   <span class="sub">
       Some text text...<br />
       An some more text...
   </span>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should fix the formatting of your answer. Edit it, and select your code. Then, press the `{}` button.

Comment: what if `.center` is inside `display:block` element? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align: middle to the div will not vertically center its contents. It will attempt to align the paragraph with the previous and following elements. Since the div is a block level element (and, so are the surrounding elements), vertical-align: middle will have no effect at all.

you can use line height to center its content.

Comment: In this case, the `div` has `display: table-cell`, which enables `vertical-align: middle` to work. @mauteri has the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0px;}
.Center { margin: 0 auto;}
```

it is welcome everywhere

Comment: This does not handle *vertical* alignment.